# Why does copy.deepcopy() behave differently for tuples than lists?

Tags: python, tuples, deep-copy

My understanding of deep-copies is that they replace references to objects with copies as new objects. Then,

Consider that:

```
>>> o = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l = [o]
>>> c = deepcopy(l)
>>> c[0] is l[0]
False
```

Compared to this:

```
>>> o = (1, 2, 3)
>>> l = [o]
>>> c = deepcopy(l)
>>> c[0] is l[0]
True
```

Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: Tuples are immutable; lists are not.

Comment: `deepcopy` is a red herring.  `(1,2,3) is (1,2,3)` returns true, and `[1,2,3] is [1,2,3]` returns false.

Comment: I see. And that's because of immutability, right?

Comment: _sort of_, it's because they're not the same reference (which is compared by `is`, rather than `==` (`.__eq__`)), while it's (presumably) an easy optimization in cPython (or whichever implementation you're using) to increment the reference count and refer to the immutable tuple

Comment: "Why is the behaviour different?" Because `deepcopy` never copies immutable built-ins as an optimization. You should *never care* what `x is y` returns when `x` and `y` are immutable types

Comment: `copy.deepcopy` is a no-op for tuples only if the tuple contains immutable objects. If you use `o = ([1], [2], [3])` in your second example, then `c[0] is l[0]` returns False. [Source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/copy.py#L220-L234).

Comment: Thank you all, makes good sense!

Comment: Further, whether or not `deepcopy` makes that particular optimization shouldn't matter; don't write code that *depends* on it. The actual use cases for `is` is fairly small and limited to much simpler situations than shown here.

Comment: The difference between shallow and deep copying only matters if you want to modify a nested object and not have it reflect in the copy. But since you can't modify a tuple, this makes no difference, so as an optimization it doesn't bother to copy the tuple.

Comment: What about frozenset? It's immutable but it returns a different object when using `deepcopy`.

Comment: @BenSmyth then perhaps simply the optimization is not being made - this may even vary between versions of Python or if you do it in the interpreter or a script and you should use `==` unless you are explicitly curious about whether something is the _same reference_ or if you are comparing to a singleton (`is True`, `is None`..)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: @ti7 I understand the difference. Like you said, I am curious about how the object references are being handled in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

`deepcopy` is redundant for immutable objects, because there's no practical way to tell the difference between a copy and the original.  Yes you can use `is` or `id()` but those don't tell you much about the object itself.

A `tuple` is immutable, as long as all of the elements it contains are immutable.  Numbers and strings are immutable so they make good tuple members.  A `list` is *never* immutable.

A class may implement a method `__deepcopy__` and if it does, that function will be called to make the copy.  That function may return the original object or a new object depending on the properties of the class.

Answer (score 0):

As John Gordon pointed out in the comments, this has nothing to do with deepcopy. Looks like your Python implementation re-uses the same object for equal tuples of literals, no matter where they appear. As in:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (1, 2, 3)
a is b  # True
```

This is an implementation detail that you cannot rely on. In CPython, the most common implementation, that line used to evaluate to `False`. Nobody guarantees that it won't return `False` again next year. I plugged the same into an online interpreter that relies on the Skulpt implementation and it returns False too [(code)](https://trinket.io/python/6d52e4b1d3).

Just use `==` for comparison!

Why does CPython store equal tuples in the same memory location? I can only speculate but it's probably to conserve memory.